# If $y = \sin^{-1} xy$, how do I verify that $xy' + y = y' \sqrt{1-x^{2}y^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The title is quite self-explanatory.

How do I compute the derivative of $y$ when $y$ is also in the right side of the equation? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely you were exposed to [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) in calculus?

Comment: Differentiate both sides simply wrt to the cariable $x$

Comment: Rearrange to $ \sin(y)=xy$ , implicitly differentiate & see what happens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is merely about the semi-finished derivative evaluation.

Derivative of $\sin^{-1}u= \dfrac{u'}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ with respect to x.

After that apply Chain Rule and Product Rule while differentiating next step.

$$y'= \dfrac {(y+ x y')}{\sqrt {1-x^2y^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \sin^{-1} xy$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac {d y}{dx} =&\dfrac {d \sin^{-1} xy}{dx} 
\end{align}
$$
By chain rule we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac {dy}{dx} =& \dfrac {d \sin^{-1} xy}{dxy}\dfrac {dxy}{dx} \\
y'=& \dfrac {1}{\sqrt {1-(xy)^2}}(xy'+y) \\
xy'+y=& y'{\sqrt {1-x^2y^2}}
\end{align}
$$